# React - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _this4.getNotes is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm learning react so i created a simple application to manage notes with a title and a description.

The application communicates with a REST API made with Go, so i can get, edit, create and delete notes.

So, the problem is the following, i have these two functions to remove and edit notes, they are in App.js File:

```
   removeNote(note) {
    fetch('http://localhost:9000/notes/delete', {
      mode: 'cors',
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(note)
    }).then(res => {
      console.log(res.text);
      this.getNotes();
    })
  }

  saveEditNote(note) {
    fetch('http://localhost:9000/notes/update', {
      mode: 'cors',
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(note)
    }).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.getNotes();
    })
  }
```

The functionallity is different, but both functions do almost the same, they send an http request to the backend, and when it gets a response, it calls the **this.getNotes();** functions to update the list of Notes.

Now, when i press the 'Delete' Button, the application deletes the note succesfully, and calls getNotes() to update the list just fine.

When i press the 'Save' Button to update a Note, the application updates the note succesfully,however, i get the following error when it calls the getNotes()

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _this4.getNotes is not a function

Question:
**Why does it fail in the Edit function, but works like a charm in the delete function?**

I have binded the function in App.js like this:

```
this.getNotes = this.getNotes.bind(this);
```

So that shouldn't be the problem.

Note component tag code:

```
cards = this.state.notes.map((note, i) => {
    return (
      <Note note={note} index={i} onRemoveNote={this.removeNote} onEditNote={this.saveEditNote} key={i}></Note>
    )
  })
```

Note component handleSaveEditNote function code:

```
handleSaveEditNote(note) {
        note.name = this.state.noteName;
        note.description = this.state.noteDescription;
        this.props.onEditNote(note)
    }
```

I made a workaround by calling the getNotes function from App.js from Note.js and then refreshing the page window.

```
getNotes() {
        this.props.onGetNotes();
        window.location.reload();
    }
```

But it's ugly and i should be able to use the getNotes function in edit function just as i use it in the delete function.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks for your time and apologies for the poor english. Have a great day!

Comment: You need to either manually bind saveEditNote function in constructor like this.saveEditNote = this.saveEditNote.bind(this); or change saveEditNote to arrow function to resolve the issue

Comment: The `this` in `removeNote()` is not bound to the component automatically, therefore `this.getNodes()` will not work. You need to make them arrow functions or use `bind()` in the `contructor`.

Comment: Every function on your component that uses `this` in its body needs to be bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the function saveEditNote too. The call site of this.getNotes() is inside saveEditNote which is happening in a different location then where getNotes is defined.

Comment: This, and the other answers are correct. I feel really dumb, i forgot to bind the saveEditNote function. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

What about the `saveEditNote(note)` and `removeNote(note)` functions? Have you bound them like you you did for the `getNotes()` function? If not, bind them or use arrow function to declare the them like this: `saveEditNote = note => {...}` and same for the `removeNote(note)` function. hope that solves your problem